# What happens if I reset SQL Server password from active directory if there are SSIS packages running using that user

Tags: sql-server, ssis, active-directory

I'll try my best to explain this. I'm not an SQL server DBA so bear with me. There are many sql SSIS packages running as a user lets say **SSIS_user**. This **SSIS_user** account is an Active directory user. These packages were created a long time ago and have been running since.

Someone gave that username and password to a person that shouldn't have gotten it... I want to reset that user password from AD. What would happen to all those SSIS packages that are running using that user ? Would they still be running after a password change.

Is the password for the user inside an SSIS packaage ? I'm a windows server guy so I have no clue and unfortunately there is no DBA so I have to look at this issue on my own.

Comment: SSIS packages run under the context is f the user that runs them. If it's already authenticated, then that authentication will remain, however, if a further attempt is made (like trying to access a file, create a new connection to a SQL instance) and the password in the service account hasn't been updated, it may well give an access denied error.

Comment: dba.StackExchange.com might be a better bet for how to do this without causing any job failures.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by service account hasn't been updated ? where is this updated ? I'm going to reset the password in Active directory, where else do I update to set the new password ? that is actually my main concern. Do I access SSMS and set that new passowrd somewhere? Is it per SSIS package ?

Comment: As I mentioned, packages run under the credentials of whomever is running it, however you haven't told us how they are running. If they are running under a service account, then the service account will need the password updated in the configuration manager. This, truthfully, sounds like your DBA and network manager (or whenever manages the user accounts) should be talking with each other.

Comment: There are no DBAs or network admins. These SSIS packages were created in 2008 and still running. This is a small company and now its up to me a sysadmin that works with exchange and winserver to look at it... No one knows anything about them other that they run. The ssis packages are running as a user account from AD like mentioned.

Comment: SSIS had changed a lot since 2008, and I assume that they have at least changed to SSISDB when they upgraded past SQL Server 2008. But still, my point stands, if they are being run by an as account, you'll need to change whatever is making the connection as that AD account; whichll be whatever is tasked to run said packages.

Comment: Ok, I've been trying to read up a bit on SQL server and it seems like sql agent is configured to run as that user. and the jobs in sql agent are running as that user as well. I assume that I'll have to change the password in sql configuration manager once I reset and it should work.